# Setting up local dev, "call to undefined function" from a module that I uninstalled a few months ago

Tags: installation

I'm attempting to set up Acquia Dev Desktop with a database dump and git repo from Pantheon.

I was using the [Computed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) module in this project but I rewrote the code in my own custom module and uninstalled Computed Field a couple months ago (uninstall from modules page and removal from my git repo afterwards).  I had no errors on the Pantheon site related to this, and I just made the db and code dump yesterday.

However, when I import into Dev Desktop, I'm getting the following error:

> Call to undefined function computed_field_entity_property_callback()
>   in
>   /Users/pk/dev/mysite/sites/all/modules/contrib/entity/modules/field.info.inc
>   on line 30

`computed_field_entity_property_callback()` is a function defined in the Computed Field module, which shouldn't exist on my site anymore.  So somehow there is a "ghost" left in my db somewhere-- **how can I locate where this error comes from**, because I can't even get a page to load-- all I'm getting is this error.

Comment: 9 times out of 10 I find this is down to cache - have you truncated the cache tables/cleared other cache bin (redis/memcache/etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time this a cache problem.

1. First try to clear the cache via Drupal (Clear cache button). Or use Drush (`drush cc all`).
2. You can clear the cache tables by truncating them. Check all the tables with `cache_` prefix.
3. If `#1` and `#2` didn't fix the problem then check if you have `Memcache` or similar installed. Flush the cache as well.
4. Another thing could be `APC` or similar opcode cache.